# Moving individual Mailbox to external drive

Tags: mail.app, archive

Does anyone know if it's possible to move a "Mailbox" in Apple Mail to an external drive? I have a relatively small SSD drive, and I'd like to create an Archive mailbox on an external drive.

I don't want to move the entire `~/Library/Mail` folder - just the Archive mbox.

If I create a MailBox called `MyArchive`, I can see the .mbox structure in `~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes/MyArchive.mbox`.

Is what I'm trying to achieve do-able? I know there's "proper" mail archiving utilities, but if I could just store the native emails on an external disk, it'd be good enough for me ...

**EDIT**: As discussed below, I've tried moving this folder to the external drive and creating a symbolic link to it, but with this in place Mail.app doesn't see the mail content in the folder -  I can see the list of mail items in the mailbox, but opening any mail in the folder results in a "blank item". 
I also see the error

`kernel[0]: Sandbox: Mail(99229) deny file-read-data /Volumes/External HD/MyArchive.mbox/` (followed by the path to the .emlx)

in Console.app.

Is there any way to "override" Mail.app's sandbox settings to allow it to read mail from the external path?

Comment: If it works on ML but doesn't on Mavericks it is unfortunately off-topic for another week or so.

Comment: I've tested it on one of my Mountain Lion Macs and it doesn't work on that either. I'll remove the Mavericks reference if it'll help to get the question off hold :)

Comment: Please add the error message you are getting on ML to the question.

Comment: Thanks - I've added our experiment with symlinks and the Console error.

Comment: Just an idea: in the Finder, try double-clicking an `.emlx` file within `/Volumes/External HD/MyArchive.mbox/`.  I suspect this might be a way to convince the sandbox that Mail is allowed to access at least that message, and perhaps the whole folder.

Comment: @Ashley: That almost works from individual mail messages. However, the "sandbox setting" appears to be lost when closing and reopening Mail.app - after relaunch I can't open the mail item again. Also, Mail still won't let me drag items into the "Archive folder" - it's as if it knows the folder is read-only :(

Comment: Thanks for trying that idea out.  Here's another idea: instead of using Finder, let's try opening it within Mail.app.  This app doesn't allow you to select a file with File > Open.  But it does have File > Import Mailboxes.  So I'd suggest: try File > Import Mailboxes, and choose /Volumes/External HD/MyArchive.mbox.  This will import it again (I don't think this will overwrite anything, but make sure you have a good backup first).  I'm hoping you can then remove the unwanted import, but the sandbox will remember that you selected that folder, and allow Mail to continue to have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Do you want this archive to show up in mail, or just be available should you need it?

If you just want to store the messages "offline" but have them around if needed at a later date you can select the mailbox in Mail, then select **Mailbox -> Export Mailbox...** (make sure you select "Export all subfolders") and save the Archive. Then you can delete the mailbox from mail and pulpit back in when needed.

Comment: Ideally, I'll like to retain the mail in Mail.app - mainly for easy searching (via Spotlight). I've tried a few of the "external archivers" (EagleFiler, for example), but none of them are as fast, seamless or simply as "nice" as being able to search for mail within the native app.

Answer (score 0):

[Update: When this question was originally posted, the version of OS X was not clear. The following solution works on OS X 10.7 Lion.]

Firstly, have a backup of all your mail in case something goes wrong and you need to restore it.

- Quit Mail.app if it's open.
- Copy `~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes/MyArchive.mbox` to the external drive (let's say the external volume is called ArchivedMail, making the volume path to the archive `/Volumes/ArchivedMail/MyArchive.mbox`).
- Delete the `~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes/MyArchive.mbox` folder.
- Link the external location using the following command in Terminal (under `/Applications/Utilities/`)

  ```
  cd ~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes
  ln -s /Volumes/ArchivedMail/MyArchive.mbox MyArchive.mbox
  ```
- Quit Terminal and open Mail.app. You'll see it using the new location for that mailbox (confirm by moving new messages to the archive).

[Note: This worked for me.]

Comment: This is what I originally tried, and although it appeared to work - I can see the list of mail items in the mailbox - opening any mail in the folder results in a "blank item". Can you open and view items that were moved to the mailbox? I also see the error `kernel[0]: Sandbox: Mail(99229) deny file-read-data /Volumes/External  HD/MyArchive.mbox/` (followed by the path to the .emlx) in Console.app ...

Comment: I think the sandbox settings on OS X 10.8 and later are preventing this from working for me :(